# Unable to send email using PHP Pear

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear, rackspace-cloud

I tried to send email using pear. Here is my code

```
<?php
require_once "/usr/share/pear/Mail.php";
require_once "/usr/share/pear/Mail/mime.php";

$to = "Info <info@mydomain.com>";
$subject = "Contact Form - mydomain.com\r\n\r\n";

$host = "smtp.zoho.com";
$username = "noreply@mydomain.com";
$password = "abc@123";
$port = "465";

//Sender Details
$sender_name = $_POST['name'];
$from = $_POST['name']." <".$_POST['email'].">";
$sender_phone = $_POST['phone'];

//Create Message
$body = $_POST['message'];
//$body = wordwrap($body, 70, "\r\n");
$body = $body . "\r\n" . "Phone: " .$sender_phone;

if($sender_name != "" && $_POST['email'] != "" && $body != "" && $sender_phone != "")
{
    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject,
      'Reply-To: ' => $from);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
      array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
      echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    } else {
      header("Location:contact-us.php?mcode=1");
    }
}
else
{
    header("Location:contact-us.php?mcode=2");
}
?>
```

Now this code gives me the following error in browser:

[image]

When I checked my php `error_log` i found this:

```
[Tue Dec 17 08:46:56 2013] [notice] child pid 7416 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /var/www/html/contact-us-process.php on line 14
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP Stack trace:
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/contact-us-process.php:0
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /var/www/html/contact-us-process.php on line 15
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP Stack trace:
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/contact-us-process.php:0
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: email in /var/www/html/contact-us-process.php on line 15
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP Stack trace:
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/contact-us-process.php:0
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: phone in /var/www/html/contact-us-process.php on line 16
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP Stack trace:
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/contact-us-process.php:0
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: message in /var/www/html/contact-us-process.php on line 19
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP Stack trace:
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:44 2013] [error] [client 117.198.137.57] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/contact-us-process.php:0
[Tue Dec 17 08:47:45 2013] [notice] child pid 6887 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Dec 17 08:50:26 2013] [notice] child pid 7414 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Dec 17 09:35:48 2013] [error] [client 117.198.124.73] File does not exist: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
[Tue Dec 17 09:39:46 2013] [notice] child pid 8617 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

I am using Rackspace cloud with Zoho email system.

When I did:

```
[root@mydomain /]# find -name Mail.php
./usr/share/pear/Mail.php
```

Thats why I directly included it in php file,

Also when I did,

```
[root@mydomain /]# find -name mime.php
./usr/share/pear/Mail/mime.php
```

So I used `require_once "/usr/share/pear/Mail/mime.php"`, However this was there in an example, I am not so sure why I used this line.

What could be the possible reason for this and how i can solve it ?

Comment: Can I have a look on your form html code? php didn't get the post value from submitted form

Comment: @crack the page gets data, as when I remove `require_once "/usr/share/pear/Mail.php";` 
`require_once "/usr/share/pear/Mail/mime.php";` It echoz everything fine

Comment: Also the chrome loader spins for minutes and then this chrome error comes, [screenshot in question]

Comment: Normally "/usr/share/pear/Mail.php" this shouldn't have access for www-data or apache2 user.
and actually you don't need to use this `require_once "/usr/share/pear/Mail.php"; require_once "/usr/share/pear/Mail/mime.php";` to send email. you just need to install postfix (mail server) and mail function for send email. if you want to use stml then I would like to suggest you to use phpmailer. just use without these required files

Comment: Django - This is the 2nd question you've posted where your PHP code is throwing SegFaults. Clearly there is something up with your server/install. It might be worth rebuilding that and redeploying to get a clean slate.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Host       = "mail.example.com"; // SMTP server example
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "username"; // SMTP account username example
$mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password example
```

You can find more about PHPMailer here: https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

Comment: But with this it gives FATAL error `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mail' not found in /var/www/html/contact-us-process.php on line 26`

Comment: I have request, try phpmailer its life saver library for sending email

Comment: and don't forget to install postfix on your machine

Comment: But i have an error with phpmailer `SMTP Error: data not accepted.` After googling for a while, I couldnt able to find any concrete solution. Could you please help.

Comment: after doing a debug I found this as a complete error `command failed: 553 Relaying disallowed SMTP Error: data not accepted. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted.`

Comment: $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
if not working then I will write the sample code for it :)

Comment: Hey I have framed it in new question, kindly review: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20635008/1182021