# Error in sending email using phpmailer - Relaying disallowed SMTP Error: data not accepted

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to send email using phpmailer, but the following code fails to send email with this error:

> SMTP ERROR: DATA END command failed: 553 Relaying disallowed SMTP Error: data not accepted. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted.

Code is below:

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.zoho.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'noreply@website.com';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '846Support.x.1';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';   
$mail->Port = 465;                         // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = $_POST['email'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];
$mail->addAddress('info@website.com');  // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$body = $_POST['message'];
$body = wordwrap($body, 70, "\r\n");
$body = $body . "\r\n" . "Phone: " .$_POST['phone'];

$mail->Subject = 'Contact Form';
$mail->Body    = $body;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit();
}
else
{
    echo 'success';
}
?>
```

Comment: the smtp message says that your mailhost don't allow relaying mails. so you need to ask your provider to allow relaying for your server

Comment: okay, so let me check with them.

Comment: I'm not finding any problem with your code. have you tried with other smtp(gmail). `$body = wordwrap($body, 70, "\r\n");` that will wrap your email body. kindly check with your mailhost provider and try with short html body

Answer (score 4):

I guess Zoho SMTP server doesn't accept sending mail with from e-mail diferent of smtp login mail.. I changed and it has passed imediatelly.

Answer (score 0):

-You can still use Zoho with little change.
- The problem: relay is disallowed because the From address (which user entered) and Sender (which you specified to be admin email) address are not matched. You can visit wp-admin/Tools/Email Log to verify.
-Work around: change From address with Sender address, you still know who is sending this email, look at Return Part.
- Hands on: go to /wp-content/plugins/postman-smtp/Postman/Postman-Mail/PostmanZendMailEngine.php, go to near end of this file and comment this line: 
$senderEmail = $sender->getEmail ();
then the address with Send value, see below for final result
   // $senderEmail = $sender->getEmail ();
   $senderEmail =  $this->transport->getFromEmailAddress ();
- It should work now.